# Why does Redux use a switch instead of taking advantage of polymorphic behaviour?

Tags: javascript, redux

I'm new to Redux, and the thing that immediately caught my eye was that Reducers switch on type.

Here's an excerpt from the [Vanilla Counter example](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/master/examples/counter-vanilla/index.html):

```
function counter(state, action) {
    if (typeof state === 'undefined') {
      return 0
    }
    switch (action.type) {
      case 'INCREMENT':
        return state + 1
      case 'DECREMENT':
        return state - 1
      default:
        return state
    }
  }

  // details omitted

  document.getElementById('increment')
    .addEventListener('click', function () {
      store.dispatch({ type: 'INCREMENT' })
    })
  document.getElementById('decrement')
    .addEventListener('click', function () {
      store.dispatch({ type: 'DECREMENT' })
    })
```

Why doesn't it use something like this instead?

```
  function increment(state) { return state + 1; }
  function decrement(state) { return state - 1; }

  function counter(state, action) {
    if (typeof state === 'undefined') {
      return 0
    }

    return action.handler(state);
  }

  // details omitted

  document.getElementById('increment')
    .addEventListener('click', function () {
      store.dispatch({ handler: increment, type: 'unused' })
    })

  document.getElementById('decrement')
    .addEventListener('click', function () {
      store.dispatch({ handler: decrement, type: 'unused' })
    })
```

Comment: You can do that if you like, redux. From Dan Abramov: Redux isn't opinionated about how you create the reducers, so indeed you can use any convention you like

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So the big reason you wouldn't want to put it inside of the action is because multiple nodes in your store may want to respond to the same action.

```
dispatch({ type: "USER_LOGIN", payload: user });
```

This might have the `user` want to react to the action, it might want the header/login/logout functionality to react, it might want the page that you're on to react, or the access-level to react.

If you've tied the behaviour of the data to the behaviour of the page, then you've erased this ability, and sort of negated the separation between the two.

There is absolutely no reason that you can't use a strategy pattern (instead of the switch) and use your functions there, instead.

```
function (state, action) {
  const strategy = {
    INCREMENT: increment,
    DECREMENT: decrement,
    default: identity
  };
  return (strategy[action.type] || strategy.default)(state, action);
}
```

The `increment` etc functions would take both state and action, in the case where they want to do some further reduction, on further nested nodes.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [redux docs](http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/Actions.html):

> Actions are plain JavaScript objects. Actions must have a type
>   property that indicates the type of action being performed. Types
>   should typically be defined as string constants.

Redux implements the [command pattern](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/learning-javascript-design/9781449334840/ch09s08.html) using POJOs, as they can be serialized recorded, and replayed. Using this pattern, you can record a series of action, and then replay (reduce the) state back to the point you wish, and that enables [hot reloading with Time travel](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xsSnOQynTHs) in redux.

This is a [great example](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/ImplementingUndoHistory.html) of using the redux command pattern to implement undo/redo easily.

By contrast the callbacks, you've suggested, can't be serialized and recorded, and this defeats the original purpose of redux.